# Evernote API key request for production use

Tags: evernote

I want to request evernote api key for production use.Can I use that requsted api key for development purpose.Please make sure will it work or not?.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The process for obtaining an Evernote API key is as follows:

1. Get a development key which works on the Evernote sandbox. To do this, go to the [Evernote Developer site](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/); on the right-hand side of the top banner area, click "Get an API Key".
2. Once you've fully tested your application, request to have your key activated on the Evernote Production service. To do this, go to the same page referenced above; on the "Resources" menu, select "Activate an API Key".

Comment: I have sent a request for Ever note API for updating the API key for production purpose.I didn't get reply from Ever note API. Now I am facing problem with the sandbox account web hook URL.I am not getting response from sandbox account web hook URL. It is a high priority.Help us. Thanks in advance

Comment: I sent a request for API key activation for production use.But I didn't get confirmation from Ever note API.And another thing is sandbox account webhook url not sending response after the above request.It is high priority.Help us how overcome this problem